# How to store weird chars in the correct way in a MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, sqlite, encode

I need to store some data in a MySQL table, but I got some problems with theese kind of characters: "ā" "æ" "ō" "ĕ" (and so on)

Till now I had theese data stored in a SQLlite database and it was great because all was good, but now I'm trying to export it in a MySQL DB, but the strange chars are stored not in the good way, even if I tried different char encode. (UTF-8, UTF-16, latin blah blah)
Does anyone know the correct way to do so?

thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utf8 needs to be established in about 4 places.

- The column(s) in the database -- Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to verify that they are explicitly set to utf8, or defaulted from the table definition.  (It is not enough to change the database *default*.)
- The connection between the client and the server.  See `SET NAMES utf8`.
- The bytes you have.
- If you are displaying the text in a web page, check the `<meta>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can switch to [BLOB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) datatype, or if you insist on using TEXT/VARCHAR/CHAR then you need to change charset of your table and database as shown below.

```
CREATE DATABASE mydbname
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

USE mydbname;

CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    `data` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

If you already have a database with `utf8` charset and collation set to `utf8_general_ci` then you can simply alter your table as mentioned below:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` CHANGE `data` `data` VARCHAR(100) 
CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT '' NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank u! your answer helped me to store the data into the DB.. but now I cannot do the select in the correct way.... If i do the select operation and print the data I see a lot of weird chars (but into the db they are ok now)